# How to start plasma-desktop from SSH-console on desktop session?

Tags: linux, ssh, opensuse, kde-4, tty

I killed KDE's plasma-desktop on a openSUSE 11.2 machine, because it was eating too much CPU. How can I restart it via SSH or another tty session? On the affected computer there is only shown a blinking cursor on the screen, but I cannot type anything.

If I try "kstart plasma-desktop" over SSH the error message of course is "kstart: cannot connect to X server", because I haven't enabled X11-forwarding. But nevertheless "kstart plasma-desktop" is not the completely correct, because I want to start plasma-desktop on a desktop session and not over SSH on my computer.

I hope I have been somewhat clear. I am looking forward to your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `DISPLAY` variable, first.  Most likely, your X server runs on display 0, so this one should work:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0
$ kstart plasma-desktop
```

Comment: Hm, I tried this, but it tells me: "kstart: cannot connect to X server :0.0"

Comment: Is X server running on any display? If not, run one.

Comment: @KB you can start one with `$ X :0`